# sql DROP CONSTRAINT UNIQUE not working

Tags: mysql, unique-constraint, sql-drop

I got the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `unsub_counts` (
 `count_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `unsub_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `unsub_count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `store_id` smallint(5) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`count_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `uc_unsub_date` (`unsub_date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

where column `unsub_date` is `unique`. Now I want to drop that uniqueness, because I need to have a unique index on `unsub_date + store_id`.

I found suggestions on the net, but is failing:

```
ALTER TABLE `unsub_counts` DROP CONSTRAINT `unsub_date`
```

gives me: **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONSTRAINT `unsub_date`' at line 1**

Is this related to MyISAM? Any other suggestions?

Comment: I don't use MySQL but it looks like you're not passing in a constraint name for one, rather a column name.

Comment: FWIW I Googled and found http://codeghar.wordpress.com/2008/03/28/drop-unique-constraint-in-mysql/ which suggests dropping the concomitant index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `drop index` with constraint name:

```
ALTER TABLE unsub_counts DROP INDEX uc_unsub_date;
```

or just:

```
drop index uc_unsub_date on unsub_counts;
```

Comment: I missed the name of the index starting with uc_. Thx, it worked